# 'System.ArgumentNullException' in WindsorContainer.Register(). Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name

Tags: castle-windsor

I try to make work a code from [aspnetboilerplate](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero).

There is a call to `WindsorContainer` class function

```
public void Register(Type type, Type impl, DependencyLifeStyle lifeStyle = DependencyLifeStyle.Singleton)
```

which looks like this:

```
iocManager.Register(
                        typeof(IRepository<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, primaryKeyType),
                        typeof(EfRepositoryBase<,,>).MakeGenericType(dbContextType, entityType, primaryKeyType),
                        DependencyLifeStyle.Transient
                        );
```

The resuting types are:

```
[System.RuntimeType] = {Name = "IRepository`2" FullName = "Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`2"}
```

and

```
base = {Name = "EfRepositoryBase`3" FullName = null}
```

We can see that the instantiated by `MakeGenericType()` concrete type's `FullName` is `null`.

The class `EfRepositoryBase3` looks like this:

```
 public class EfRepositoryBase<TDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
        where TDbContext : DbContext
    {
         ... CRUD methods...
    }
```

Why the `FullName` of it is `null` and how the issue could be overcome?

Answer (score 1):

[FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx) can return null in some cases

> The fully qualified name of the Type, including the namespace of the
>   Type but not the assembly; or null if the current instance represents
>   a generic type parameter, an array type, pointer type, or byref type
>   based on a type parameter, or a generic type that is not a generic
>   type definition but contains unresolved type parameters.

You can get a non null name by using the [`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) method.